# faild to load image in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am tring to add image to react project. i use `import image from "./ImageSource"`

when i import a local image like

```
import image from "./images/image.jpg";
...
return <img src={image} />
```

it appeare successfully.

but when i try to import image with link like "https://picsum.photos/id/0/500" it doesn't work and error show saying

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/jpeg". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
__________________________________
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://i.picsum.photos/id/0/1000/1000.jpg?hmac=2UP1ceqLjSmxh6sZh1wmL6yWx3nIMPvw2_b0ugpOv1o
```

this is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import image from "https://picsum.photos/id/0/500";

function Image() {
   const {width, height} = useParams()
   return (
        <section className="container p-y-3">
            <h1 className="clr-primary">Create Image</h1>
            <h2>{width}</h2>
            <h2>{height}</h2>
            {/* The problem here */}
            <img src={image} alt="" />
            <img src={require("https://picsum.photos/id/0/500")} />
        </section>
    );
}

export default Image
```

How can i import image from link?

Comment: Unless I've missed something you can't import/require images (locally or internetly) like that - why not assign the URI to a string and use that in the JSX? `const image = "https://picsum.photos/id/0/500";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution.
I don't need to import the url or require it.
I should write it as string.

```
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/1000"
```

Thank you all